# OR statement within CSS selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

One might use a CSS selector such as `a[href^="http:"], a[href^="mailto:"]` to match all external and mail links within a document, but is there a way to use an "or" statement within the quotes section of the selector like so: `a[href^="(http|mailto):"]`?

Comment: The first selector you mentioned will do what you want...

Comment: @sevenseacat: Isn't that what he said?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do what you're asking. In the CSS selector spec, the pipe character is used for something different when used with attribute selectors. It's used as a namespace separator.

Per the selector spec on the W3C:

> The attribute name in an attribute selector is given as a CSS
>   qualified name: a namespace prefix that has been previously declared
>   may be prepended to the attribute name separated by the namespace
>   separator "vertical bar" (|). In keeping with the Namespaces in the
>   XML recommendation, default namespaces do not apply to attributes,
>   therefore attribute selectors without a namespace component apply only
>   to attributes that have no namespace (equivalent to "|attr"; these
>   attributes are said to be in the "per-element-type namespace
>   partition"). An asterisk may be used for the namespace prefix
>   indicating that the selector is to match all attribute names without
>   regard to the attribute's namespace.

```
CSS examples:

@namespace foo "http://www.example.com";
[foo|att=val] { color: blue }
[*|att] { color: yellow }
[|att] { color: green }
[att] { color: green }
```

> The first rule will match only elements with the attribute att in the
>   "http://www.example.com" namespace with the value "val".
>
> The second rule will match only elements with the attribute att
>   regardless of the namespace of the attribute (including no namespace).
>
> The last two rules are equivalent and will match only elements with
>   the attribute att where the attribute is not in a namespace.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attrnmsp

Comment: There's also [`[att|=val]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation), an attribute selector that matches by attribute with either exactly `val` or a value that's prefixed with `val-`, but as with namespace prefixes it does not provide the functionality being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I was checking the CSS Selectors grammar, but seems like the only way to do this is with the comma separator:

```
selectors_group
  : selector [ COMMA S* selector ]*
```

Also, these are some relevant lexical rules:

```
{w}"+"           return PLUS;
{w}">"           return GREATER;
{w}","           return COMMA;
{w}"~"           return TILDE;
```

There are not **AND** nor **OR** rules, but one thing I noted is that they have negation:

```
"{N}{O}{T}"("  return NOT;)
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#w3cselgrammar

Comment: The symbols are combinators (except the `,`). That negation simply refers to the `:not()` pseudo-class, so it isn't anything special.

Comment: @BoltClock: I know isn't anything special, I just mentioned few things (relevants for me) I found on the css selector spec. Should I remove my answer?